TLSF Allocator for #![no_std] environment
https://github.com/Lousifr-Illuminos/IlluminOS/tree/main
Little project I'm trying for the sake of learning.  It works when attempting to allocate variables sized u8 through u128, as well as creating an empty vector but when trying to push values to the vector, QEMU will crash and be stuck in a cycle of booting then crashing.
let smallest: Box<u8> = Box::<u8>::new(u8::MAX);             // This is successful.
let empty_vec: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();                         // This is successful.
empty_vec.push(32);                                          // This fails.
let mut vec_with_capacity: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(10); // This is successful.
vec_with_capacity[0] = 32;                                   // This fails.

When placing brackets around an allocation, the code within that scope will execute, but then at the end of the scope, it will fail as it is unable to validate the heap.
if let Err(e) = self.validate_heap() {
    panic!("Heap validation failed after deallocation: {}", e);
}

pub fn validate_heap(&self) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
  if !block.is_free {
      return Err("Free block marked as allocated"); // this is the Err that is returned.
  }
}

I've implemented the GlobalAlloc trait:
unsafe impl GlobalAlloc for TLSF {
    unsafe fn alloc(&self, layout: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
        self.alloc(layout)
    }

    unsafe fn dealloc(&self, ptr: *mut u8, layout: Layout) {
        self.dealloc(ptr, layout)
    }
}

#[global_allocator]
pub static ALLOCATOR: TLSF = TLSF::new();

This is the code for alloc():
fn alloc(&self, layout: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
    let size = layout.size().max(layout.align()).max(BLOCK_SIZE_MIN);
    let align = layout.align().max(8);

    let size = (size + align - 1) & !(align - 1);

    let (first_level, second_level) = self.get_suitable_block(size);

    if let Some(block_ptr) = self.find_free_block(first_level, second_level) {
        let block = unsafe { &mut *block_ptr.as_ptr() };

        self.remove_free_block(block_ptr, first_level, second_level);

        let block_start = block_ptr.as_ptr() as usize;
        let aligned_start = (block_start + align - 1) & !(align - 1);
        let alignment_offset = aligned_start - block_start;

        if block.size >= size + alignment_offset {
            if alignment_offset > 0 {
                let padding_block = block_ptr.as_ptr();
                unsafe {
                    (*padding_block).size = alignment_offset;
                    (*padding_block).next = AtomicPtr::new(ptr::null_mut());
                }
                let (padding_first_level, padding_second_level) =
                    self.get_index_for_size(alignment_offset);
                self.add_free_block(padding_block, padding_first_level, padding_second_level);
            }

            let aligned_block = aligned_start as *mut Block;
            unsafe {
                (*aligned_block).size = block.size - alignment_offset;
                (*aligned_block).is_free = false; // Mark as not free

                if (*aligned_block).size > size {
                    self.split_block(aligned_block, size);
                }
            }

            let result_ptr = aligned_block as *mut u8;

            debug_assert!(
                result_ptr as usize % align == 0,
                "Misaligned allocation: {:p} with align {}",
                result_ptr,
                align
            );

            result_ptr
        } else {
            ptr::null_mut()
        }
    } else {
        ptr::null_mut()
    }
}

This is the code for dealloc():
fn dealloc(&self, ptr: *mut u8, layout: Layout) {
    if ptr.is_null() {
        return;
    }

    let block_ptr = (ptr as usize & !(BLOCK_SIZE_MIN - 1)) as *mut Block;
    let block = unsafe { &mut *block_ptr };

    // Mark the block as free
    block.is_free = true;

    // Merge with adjacent blocks
    self.merge_block(block_ptr);

    let (first_level, second_level) = self.get_index_for_size(block.size);
    self.add_free_block(block_ptr, first_level, second_level);

    if let Err(e) = self.validate_heap() {
        panic!("Heap validation failed after deallocation: {}", e);
    }
}

Minimal example:
use core::alloc::{GlobalAlloc, Layout};
use core::mem::MaybeUninit;
use core::ptr::{self, NonNull};
use core::sync::atomic::{AtomicPtr, Ordering};

extern crate alloc;
use alloc::boxed::Box;

const BLOCK_SIZE_MIN: usize = 8;
const FIRST_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT: usize = 32;
const SECOND_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT: usize = 16;
pub const HEAP_START: usize = 0x_4444_4444_0000;
pub const HEAP_SIZE: usize = 512 * 1024; // 0.5 MiB

#[derive(Debug)]
#[repr(C, align(8))]
struct Block {
    size: usize,
    is_free: bool,
    next: AtomicPtr<Block>,
}

pub struct TLSF {
    blocks: [[AtomicPtr<Block>; SECOND_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT]; FIRST_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT],
}

impl TLSF {
    pub const fn new() -> Self {
        let blocks: [[MaybeUninit<AtomicPtr<Block>>; SECOND_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT];
            FIRST_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT] = unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() };

        let mut blocks = blocks;
        let mut i = 0;
        while i < FIRST_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT {
            let mut j = 0;
            while j < SECOND_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT {
                blocks[i][j] = MaybeUninit::new(AtomicPtr::new(core::ptr::null_mut()));
                j += 1;
            }
            i += 1;
        }

        TLSF {
            blocks: unsafe { core::mem::transmute(blocks) },
        }
    }

    pub unsafe fn init(&self, heap_start: usize, heap_size: usize) {
        println!(
            "Initializing heap: start={:x}, size={}",
            heap_start, heap_size
        );
        let aligned_start = (heap_start + BLOCK_SIZE_MIN - 1) & !(BLOCK_SIZE_MIN - 1);
        let aligned_size = heap_size.saturating_sub(aligned_start.saturating_sub(heap_start));
        println!(
            "Aligned heap: start={:x}, size={}",
            aligned_start, aligned_size
        );
        if aligned_size < BLOCK_SIZE_MIN {
            panic!("Heap size too small");
        }
        let block_ptr = aligned_start as *mut Block;
        (*block_ptr).size = aligned_size;
        (*block_ptr).next = AtomicPtr::new(core::ptr::null_mut());
        let (first_level, second_level) = self.get_index_for_size(aligned_size);
        println!(
            "Initial block: size={}, first_level={}, second_level={}",
            aligned_size, first_level, second_level
        );
        self.add_free_block(block_ptr, first_level, second_level);
    }

    fn alloc(&self, layout: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
        let size = layout.size().max(layout.align()).max(BLOCK_SIZE_MIN);
        let align = layout.align().max(8);

        let size = (size + align - 1) & !(align - 1);

        let (first_level, second_level) = self.get_suitable_block(size);

        if let Some(block_ptr) = self.find_free_block(first_level, second_level) {
            let block = unsafe { &mut *block_ptr.as_ptr() };

            self.remove_free_block(block_ptr, first_level, second_level);

            let block_start = block_ptr.as_ptr() as usize;
            let aligned_start = (block_start + align - 1) & !(align - 1);
            let alignment_offset = aligned_start - block_start;

            if block.size >= size + alignment_offset {
                if alignment_offset > 0 {
                    let padding_block = block_ptr.as_ptr();
                    unsafe {
                        (*padding_block).size = alignment_offset;
                        (*padding_block).next = AtomicPtr::new(ptr::null_mut());
                    }
                    let (padding_first_level, padding_second_level) =
                        self.get_index_for_size(alignment_offset);
                    self.add_free_block(padding_block, padding_first_level, padding_second_level);
                }

                let aligned_block = aligned_start as *mut Block;
                unsafe {
                    (*aligned_block).size = block.size - alignment_offset;
                    (*aligned_block).is_free = false; // Mark as not free

                    if (*aligned_block).size > size {
                        self.split_block(aligned_block, size);
                    }
                }

                let result_ptr = aligned_block as *mut u8;

                debug_assert!(
                    result_ptr as usize % align == 0,
                    "Misaligned allocation: {:p} with align {}",
                    result_ptr,
                    align
                );

                result_ptr
            } else {
                ptr::null_mut()
            }
        } else {
            ptr::null_mut()
        }
    }

    fn dealloc(&self, ptr: *mut u8, layout: Layout) {
        if ptr.is_null() {
            return;
        }

        let block_ptr = (ptr as usize & !(BLOCK_SIZE_MIN - 1)) as *mut Block;
        let block = unsafe { &mut *block_ptr };

        // Mark the block as free
        block.is_free = true;

        // Merge with adjacent blocks
        self.merge_block(block_ptr);

        let (first_level, second_level) = self.get_index_for_size(block.size);
        self.add_free_block(block_ptr, first_level, second_level);
    }

    fn get_suitable_block(&self, size: usize) -> (usize, usize) {
        let size = size.max(BLOCK_SIZE_MIN);
        let mut first_level =
            (size.ilog2() as usize).saturating_sub(BLOCK_SIZE_MIN.ilog2() as usize);
        if first_level >= FIRST_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT {
            first_level = FIRST_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT - 1;
        }
        let second_level = ((size >> first_level) - 1) & (SECOND_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT - 1);
        (first_level, second_level)
    }

    fn find_free_block(
        &self,
        mut first_level: usize,
        mut second_level: usize,
    ) -> Option<NonNull<Block>> {
        while first_level < FIRST_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT {
            for level in second_level..SECOND_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT {
                let block_ptr = self.blocks[first_level][level].load(Ordering::Acquire);
                if !block_ptr.is_null() {
                    let block = unsafe { &*block_ptr };
                    if block.size >= BLOCK_SIZE_MIN {
                        return NonNull::new(block_ptr);
                    }
                }
            }
            first_level += 1;
            second_level = 0;
        }
        None
    }

    fn get_previous_block(&self, block_ptr: *mut Block) -> Option<*mut Block> {
        let heap_start = HEAP_START as *mut Block;
        let heap_end = unsafe { heap_start.add(HEAP_SIZE / core::mem::size_of::<Block>()) };

        // Check if the block_ptr is within the heap bounds and properly aligned
        if block_ptr < heap_start || block_ptr >= heap_end || (block_ptr as usize) % 8 != 0 {
            println!("Block pointer is out of heap bounds or misaligned");
            return None;
        }

        // If it's the first block, there's no previous block
        if block_ptr == heap_start {
            println!("Block is the first block in the heap");
            return None;
        }

        let mut current = heap_start;

        while current < block_ptr {
            let current_size = unsafe { (*current).size };
            println!("Current block: {:p}, size: {}", current, current_size);

            // Ensure the current size is at least the minimum block size
            if current_size < BLOCK_SIZE_MIN {
                println!("Error: Invalid block size");
                return None;
            }

            let next = unsafe { (current as *mut u8).add(current_size) as *mut Block };

            // Ensure the next block is properly aligned
            if (next as usize) % 8 != 0 {
                println!("Error: Next block is misaligned");
                return None;
            }

            // If the next block would be our target block, we've found the previous
            if next == block_ptr {
                println!("Found previous block: {:p}", current);
                return Some(current);
            }

            // If we've gone past our target block, something is wrong
            if next > block_ptr {
                println!("Error: Went past target block");
                return None;
            }

            current = next;
        }

        // If we've reached here, we didn't find a previous block
        println!("No previous block found");
        None
    }

    fn add_free_block(&self, block: *mut Block, first_level: usize, second_level: usize) {
        let block_ref = unsafe { &mut *block };
        if block_ref.size < BLOCK_SIZE_MIN {
            println!("Error: Attempting to add a block smaller than BLOCK_SIZE_MIN");
            return;
        }
        block_ref.is_free = true;
        let current_head = self.blocks[first_level][second_level].load(Ordering::Relaxed);
        block_ref.next.store(current_head, Ordering::Relaxed);
        self.blocks[first_level][second_level].store(block, Ordering::Release);
    }

    fn remove_free_block(&self, block: NonNull<Block>, first_level: usize, second_level: usize) {
        let block_ref = unsafe { block.as_ref() };
        let next_ptr = block_ref.next.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
        self.blocks[first_level][second_level].store(next_ptr, Ordering::Release);
    }

    fn split_block(&self, block_ptr: *mut Block, size: usize) {
        unsafe {
            let block = &mut *block_ptr;
            let remaining_size = block.size - size;
            if remaining_size >= BLOCK_SIZE_MIN {
                let new_block_ptr = (block_ptr as *mut u8).add(size) as *mut Block;
                let new_block = &mut *new_block_ptr;
                new_block.size = remaining_size;
                new_block.next = AtomicPtr::new(ptr::null_mut());
                new_block.is_free = true; // Mark the new block as free

                block.size = size;
                block.is_free = false; // Mark the allocated block as not free

                let (first_level, second_level) = self.get_index_for_size(remaining_size);
                self.add_free_block(new_block_ptr, first_level, second_level);
            } else {
                block.is_free = false; // Mark the entire block as not free if we can't split
            }
        }
    }

    fn merge_block(&self, block_ptr: *mut Block) {
        if block_ptr.is_null() {
            return;
        }

        let mut current_ptr = block_ptr;
        let mut current_block = unsafe { &mut *current_ptr };
        let mut total_size = current_block.size;

        // Check and merge with the previous block
        if let Some(prev_block_ptr) = self.get_previous_block(block_ptr) {
            let prev_block = unsafe { &mut *prev_block_ptr };
            if prev_block.is_free {
                let (prev_first_level, prev_second_level) =
                    self.get_index_for_size(prev_block.size);
                self.remove_free_block(
                    NonNull::new(prev_block_ptr).unwrap(),
                    prev_first_level,
                    prev_second_level,
                );
                total_size += prev_block.size;
                current_ptr = prev_block_ptr;
                current_block = unsafe { &mut *current_ptr };
            }
        }

        // Check and merge with the next block
        let next_block_ptr =
            unsafe { (current_ptr as *mut u8).add(current_block.size) as *mut Block };
        if !next_block_ptr.is_null() {
            let next_block = unsafe { &mut *next_block_ptr };
            if next_block.is_free {
                let (next_first_level, next_second_level) =
                    self.get_index_for_size(next_block.size);
                self.remove_free_block(
                    NonNull::new(next_block_ptr).unwrap(),
                    next_first_level,
                    next_second_level,
                );
                total_size += next_block.size;
            }
        }

        // Update the size of the merged block
        current_block.size = total_size;
        current_block.is_free = true; // Ensure the merged block is marked as free
    }

    fn get_index_for_size(&self, size: usize) -> (usize, usize) {
        if size < BLOCK_SIZE_MIN {
            return (0, 0);
        }
        let first_level = ((size.ilog2() as usize).saturating_sub(BLOCK_SIZE_MIN.ilog2() as usize))
            .min(FIRST_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT - 1);
        let second_level = ((size >> first_level) - 1) & (SECOND_LEVEL_INDEX_COUNT - 1);
        (first_level, second_level)
    }
}

unsafe impl GlobalAlloc for TLSF {
    unsafe fn alloc(&self, layout: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
        self.alloc(layout)
    }

    unsafe fn dealloc(&self, ptr: *mut u8, layout: Layout) {
        self.dealloc(ptr, layout)
    }
}

#[global_allocator]
pub static ALLOCATOR: TLSF = TLSF::new();

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        ALLOCATOR.init(HEAP_START, HEAP_SIZE);
    }
    let test: Box<u8> = Box::new(32);
    println!("Test: {} at address {:p}", *test, test);
}


Please add a [mre]. In particular, what is block in validate_heap? And how does your alloc work?

@Jmb Does this work as a minimal reproducible example, or must I further edit this post?

I'll edit this to include a better (reproducible) example when I get off work today.

The example needs to be reproducible, so it should include all the code required to test it. Here you obviously have a linked list for the free blocks, there is a better than average chance that the bug is in the linked list code (because linked lists are very hard to get right in any language) but you didn't include this code…

Included a GitHub link to a repository containing this allocator.

In alloc you call find_free_block, which looks for a suitable block starting at position (first_level, second_level). This may return a block from another position if the first one isn't available (say position (l1, l2)). However you then call remove_free_block (…, first_level, second_level). You now have the same linked list in two positions: at (first_level, second_level) the list starting from block.next and at (l1, l2) the list starting from block.

As side effects: block is still present in self.blocks at position (l1, l2) even though it has been allocated. And you've also lost the blocks from the list that was stored at (first_level, second_level) before the call to remove_free_block.
